# Group action of $\mathbb{Z}_3$ on the complex plane by rotations.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-actions

Consider the action of $\mathbb{Z}_3$ on the complex plane by rotations. Which of these pairs of complex numbers are in the same orbit?

**A:** $1$ and $e^{\frac{i\pi}{2}}$

**B:** $1$ and $e^{\frac{i\pi}{3}}$

**C:** $e^{\frac{i\pi}{3}}$ and $e^{\frac{-2i\pi}{3}}$

**D:** $e^{\frac{i\pi}{3}}$ and $e^{\frac{-i\pi}{3}}$

**What I know so far:**

For $\bar{k}\in\mathbb{Z}_3$ and $z\in\mathbb{C}$  $$\bar{k} \cdot z= e^{\frac{2ik\pi}{n}} \times z $$

Hence for $\bar{0}$ we get $1$ which rules out *C* and *D*.
For $\bar{1}$ we get $e^{\frac{2i\pi}{3}}$ but that is not an option.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint/solution:** Each orbit has three elements, except for the orbit of the origin, which is a singleton. Two complex numbers $z$ and $w$ are in the same orbit if $|z|=|w|$ and the angle between them is $2\pi/3$. This immediately rules out everything except for option D, whose elements form an angle of $(\pi/3)-(-\pi/3)=2\pi/3$.

Comment: Yes. Think geometrically about what's happening.